# How to get $\sup_{P(x)\in V} |P'(0)|$?

Tags: analysis

Let
$$
V=\{P(x)= ax^2 +bx +c    ~:~a,b,c\in \mathbb R;~a\ne0;~  |P(x)|\le 1 ,~ \forall x\in[0,1]\}
$$
then how to get
$$
\sup_{P(x)\in V} |P'(0)|
$$

PS: This is the question my student asked me. But I can't. So, ask here for help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sup_{P(x)\in V} |P'(0)|=\sup_{P(x)\in V}|b|$

Since the restriction is on the absolute value of $P(x)$ ($|P(x)|<1$), without loss of generality we can assume $a>0$. Now, there are three possibilities for the point which makes $P(x)$ minimum (i.e. $x^*$): $x^*$ is smaller than 1, or it is between 0 and 1, or it is greater than 1.

Since $P(x)$ has symmetry with respect to $x=\frac{-b}{2a}$, without loss of generality we can investigate only two cases: $x^*$ is between 0 and 1, or it is greater than 1.

case1: $x^*$ is between 0 and 1:

$0\le x^*=\frac{-b}{2a}\le1$, then we have:

$-1\le P(x^*)$

$P(0)\le1$

$P(1)\le1$

These conditions give $c=1$ and $a+b=0$ and $b^2 \le 8a$. So, $b=-a=-8$.

This is because:
$P(0)\le1$ implies $c \le 1$ or $-1 \le -c$. Also $-1\le P(x^*)$ implies $-1 \le c - \frac{b^2}{4a}$. Hence, $-2 \le -1 -c \le -\frac{b^2}{4a}$. Finally, $2 \ge \frac{b^2}{4a}$, and since $a$ is positive we have $b^2 \le 8a$

Case 2:  $1\le \frac{-b}{2a}$:

In this case the best option is $P(0)=c=1$ and $-1\le P(1)$. So, we have:

$2a\le -b$

$-1 \le a+b+1$

These consitions give $a=2$ and $b=4$.

Comparing two cases, $sup |b|=8$

Comment: Thanks. In the case 1, how do you get $b^2 <8a$ ?

Comment: $P(0)\le1$ implies $c \le 1$ or $-1 \le -c$. Also $-1\le P(x^*)$ implies $-1 \le c - \frac{b^2}{4a}$. Hence, $-2 \le -1 -c \le -\frac{b^2}{4a}$. Finally, $2 \ge \frac{b^2}{4a}$, and since $a$ is positive we have $b^2 \le 8a$. I add this to the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $8$ realized by $P(x)=8x^2-8x+1$ as clearly $P(x) \le 1, x \in [0,1]$ while $P(x)+1=2(2x-1)^2 \ge 0$ and $|P'(0)|=8$

Now if $|P'(0)|=|b| >8$ we can assume wlog $b<0$ (as $|P(x)|=|-P(x)|$) and then we have $c \le 1, -1 \le a+b+c \le 1$ so $-2 \le a-|b| \le 0$ or $0<|b|/2 < |b|-2 \le a \le |b|$ hence $-b/(2a)=|b|/(2a) \in [0,1]$ and $|P(-b/(2a))|=|\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}| \le 1$ implies $b^2 \le 4ac+4a \le 8a \le 8|b|$ or $|b| \le 8$ Contradiction!